# Cloning hard drive with Ubuntu disks

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, clone, disk-image

I am trying to clone hard drive on my laptop. Clonezilla does not work for me, I cannot boot from usb-drive and my cd-rom is acting weirdly (not Clonezilla's fault).

So I am thinking about booting Ubuntu from flash-usb and using 'Disks' program. It has graphical interface and allows creating images. (I am not too friendly with command line, so I like GUI).

Did anybody use it before, what are results, words of caution?

Regards,

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: You will find that the disc imaging in `disks` is probably not what you want, as you will need a third disc for the image. You are better off with `gparted` (also on Ubuntu Live discs). This provides a GUI front-end to the programs in @hackwarewright's link: it's straightforward to use and provides quite a lot of checks against data loss.

Comment: why can't you create a proper bootable drive with clonezilla?

Comment: @jiggunjer here is my post on clonezilla forum

Comment: @AFH, so if I boot from UBS flash, I will not be able to make a copy (with 'Disks') of local C: drive to attached USB hard drive?

Comment: You can create an image (if the drive is big enough to hold it), but you will then have to restore this to another drive - it will not be a bootable clone; in contrast `gparted` will allow you to clone from drive to drive directly.